# How to speed up state of charge constraint in Pyomo model

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, pyomo

**Context:** I am working on a small electricity market model in Pyomo. It optimizes the capacity of different technologies and generation in at least 43800 hours. One of the technologies is a battery. Among several constraints for this technology, one specifies the state of charge across hours. Here's what it looks like:

```
def socstatetrans(model,s,h):
  if model.Hour[h] == 1: 
    return model.soc0 + sqrt(model.beff)*model.ch[s,h] - model.disch[s,h]/sqrt(model.beff) == model.soc[s,h]
  else: 
    return model.soc[s,h-1] + sqrt(model.beff)*model.ch[s,h] - model.disch[s,h]/sqrt(model.beff) == model.soc[s,h]

model.sochourly = Constraint(model.Stor, model.Hour, rule = socstatetrans)
```

**Problem:** Adding the constraint to the model takes about three minutes in Google Colab. As I have to run the model many times, this is too long. I suspect that my code is somehow inefficient and would appreciate any tips on how to rewrite the constraint to speed this up.

Comment: What version of Pyomo are you using? What are you changing in the model between runs?

Comment: @funkypenguin, It would be worth writing something like that: (m.c1 = Constraint(m.J, rule=lambda m, j: LHS >= RHS)). where m is the model instant, (J/j) is an index. Do you try this?